# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, jdbc-postgres

while handling large Db transaction 
I encountered the following problem :

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open
>   at org.apache.commons.pool.BaseObjectPool.assertOpen(BaseObjectPool.java:78)
>   at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:722)
>   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:95)
>   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
>   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
>   at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
>   at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
>   at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:119)
>   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
>   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1326)
> at com.indictranstech.mbmc.common.utils.AuditTrailHibernateListener.onPostInsert(AuditTrailHibernateListener.java:133)
>   at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:131)
>   at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:110)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
>   at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
>   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
>   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
>   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
>   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
>   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
>   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
>   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
>   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:375)
>   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at $Proxy53.merge(Unknown Source)
> ```

DB connection is managed by HibernateTemplate.
while transaction is managed by Spring Transaction Management.
database is PostgreSQL.

The same code works fine when there are 5 to 10 transactions.

Comment: Can you put in the datasource configuration?

Answer (score -1):

Did you use code like this in your project?

```
Session session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

when you use openSession(),spring will not close it automatically,you shoud use it like this

```
HttpSession session = null;
session  = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
if(null == session) {
    session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

you can also use hibernate.executeFind(new HibernateCallback(){ ... }) to avoid this problem

Comment: openSession returns Session (org.hibernate.Session) not httpSession.

Comment: Not completely corrected and this does not solve the problem. The problem is not connection leak but about the pool itself is closed. Most likely, spring is calling close method on connection pool.